# Entity Framework Join with a table of another join

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I'm using C# with Entity Framework on an Oracle database and I'm trying to reproduce this query with LINQ.

```sql
SELECT pc.tkpordlav, aa.cdarti, aa.cdartm
FROM ss_posordlav_cum pc
INNER JOIN mrp_arch_articoli aa on pc.cdarti = aa.cdarti
LEFT JOIN pzz_mpssupp pm on pc.tkmpssupp = pm.tkmpssupp
LEFT JOIN mrp_file_testoper a on pm.noper = a.nroper
LEFT JOIN mrp_file_testoper b on pc.noper = b.nroper
WHERE pc.tktordlav = '8971'
ORDER BY aa.cdartm ASC
```

So far i managed to do this

```cs
var query = (
    from pc in modelContext.SS_POSORDLAV_CUM
    join aa in modelContext.MRP_ARCH_ARTICOLI on pc.CDARTI equals aa.CDARTI
    join pm in modelContext.PZZ_MPSSUPP on pc.TKMPSSUPP equals pm.TKMPSSUPP into pmGroup
    from pm in pmGroup.DefaultIfEmpty()
    join b in modelContext.MRP_FILE_TESTOPER on pc.NOPER equals b.NROPER into bGroup
    from b in bGroup.DefaultIfEmpty()
    join a in modelContext.MRP_FILE_TESTOPER on pm.NOPER equals a.NROPER into aGroup
    from a in aGroup.DefaultIfEmpty()
    where pc.TKTORDLAV == tkt
    orderby aa.CDARTM ascending
    select new TEST {
        TKPORDLAV = pc.TKPORDLAV,
        CDARTI = aa.CDARTI,
        CDARTM = aa.CDARTM
    }
).ToListAsync();
```

but it gives me the error

```
The type of one of the expressions in the join clause is incorrect. Type inference failed on call to 'GroupJoin'. [Posordlav_cum]csharp(CS1941)
```

with the join a

Model classes for

- MRP_ARCH_TESTOPER https://pastebin.com/Kv8akZ9t
- PZZ_MPSSUPP https://pastebin.com/1UYWnbRi

Comment: Show model classes for `PZZ_MPSSUPP` and `MRP_FILE_TESTOPER`.

Comment: Use navigation properties, don't join. Use the full power of EF.

Comment: Please add the (essential!) code to the question text. Questions shouldn't depend on external sources.

Comment: `PZZ_MPSSUPP.NOPER` is `int?` but `MRP_FILE_TESTOPER.NOPER` is `decimal`. Convert to `decimal`  or to `int?` equals parts. `(decimal)pm.NOPER.Value equals a.NROPER into aGroup`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

the query syntax is correct.  The issue must be a data type problem or a data missing error.  you can use linqpad to see the resulting sql from the linq statement. https://www.linqpad.net/

```
  var query = (
        from pc in db.SS_POSORDLAV_CUM
        join aa in db.MRP_ARCH_ARTICOLI on pc.CDARTI equals aa.CDARTI
    
        join pm in db.PZZ_MPSSUPP on pc.TKMPSSUPP equals pm.TKMPSSUPP into pmGroup
        from pm in pmGroup.DefaultIfEmpty()
    
        join b in db.MRP_FILE_TESTOPER on pc.NOPER equals b.NROPER into bGroup
        from b in bGroup.DefaultIfEmpty()
    
        join a in db.MRP_FILE_TESTOPER on pm.NOPER equals a.NROPER into aGroup
        from a in aGroup.DefaultIfEmpty()
    
        where pc.TKTORDLAV == tktordlav
        orderby aa.CDARTM ascending
        select new TEST {
            TKPORDLAV = pc.TKPORDLAV,
            CDARTI = aa.CDARTI,
            CDARTM = aa.CDARTM
        }var query = (
        from pc in db.SS_POSORDLAV_CUM
        join aa in db.MRP_ARCH_ARTICOLI on pc.CDARTI equals aa.CDARTI
    
        join pm in db.PZZ_MPSSUPP on pc.TKMPSSUPP equals pm.TKMPSSUPP into pmGroup
        from pm in pmGroup.DefaultIfEmpty()
    
        join b in db.MRP_FILE_TESTOPER on pc.NOPER equals b.NROPER into bGroup
        from b in bGroup.DefaultIfEmpty()
    
        join a in db.MRP_FILE_TESTOPER on pm.NOPER equals a.NROPER into aGroup
        from a in aGroup.DefaultIfEmpty()
    
        where pc.TKTORDLAV == tktordlav
        orderby aa.CDARTM ascending
        select new TEST {
            TKPORDLAV = pc.TKPORDLAV,
            CDARTI = aa.CDARTI,
            CDARTM = aa.CDARTM
        }
```